# Open the files in my application

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, file, uikit

I am having an application which consists of many different file formats like ppt,pdf,txt,png etc, I want to open it whenever the user taps the particular file. How this can be done?Please help me

Can I use WebView for all the files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the quick look framework with UIDocumentInteractionController class it will have you to open different format of file in its view controller..
QuickLook is a framework that provides quick previewing of a range of document types – supported documents include iWork documents, Microsoft Office, Rich Text Format, PDF, images, text files and comma-separated (csv) files.
[Sample Application](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html)

Comment: I cannot view the ppt file :( , is there any other way ?

Comment: A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

    iWork documents

    Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)

    Rich Text Format (RTF) documents

    PDF files

    Images

    Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)

    Comma-separated value (csv) files

Answer (score 1):

UIWebview allow you to display office documents :

You can open them by loading the file data, example with RTF file :

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
[self.webView loadData:myData MIMEType:@"application/rtf" textEncodingName:@"latin1" baseURL:nil];
```

Or you can load them by creating a request with local path :

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithStringdfPath];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Note that for Office documents with complex layout you will have a very (very) poor rendering.
The only solution is to call a separate application that handles this kind of documents (Pages, Quick office, etc)

Have a look at UIDocumentInteractionController to open your documents in another app

Hope this helps,
Vincent